# Can I fall back to latin1 if there are illegal bytes?

Tags: encoding

The help text for `fileencodings` says this:

> This is a list of character encodings considered when starting to edit
>       an existing file.  When a file is read, Vim tries to use the first
>       mentioned character encoding.  If an error is detected, the next one
>       in the list is tried.  When an encoding is found that works,
>       'fileencoding' is set to it.

Since all byte strings are valid `latin1` text, but `utf-8` is more common, I have set my `fileencodings` as:

```
set fileencodings=utf-8,latin1
```

However, vim appears to use `utf-8` even when there are decoding errors. A minimal example is the file containing the bytes `0x00 0xfd`:

```
% xxd test.in
00000000: 00fd                                     ..
% vim test.in
"test.in" [noeol][ILLEGAL BYTE in line 1] 1L, 2C
:set fileencoding?
fileencoding=utf-8
```

Why is this? How can I ask vim to fall back to latin1 when it sees illegal bytes?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with your example is `[noeol]`. Note that the bytes `00 DF` do not really make a file that a text editor expects; if you add a newline to the end (`00 DF 0A`), you *definitely* won't get the `[noeol]` error, and I suspect that the file will now correctly open as latin1 (it does in my tests), and you'll see something like `<00>ý` or `^@ý`. I'm not sure if this is what you expect or not - but latin1 is an 8-bit encoding, so your file consists of a literal NULL (which vim doesn't have a good way to print, so it prints as `<00>` if you have `display=uhex` set, or `^@` if not) followed by the character at `DF`, `ý`.

Note that `00` is NULL in ASCII, I'm not even sure if it's valid in latin1, but (for me at least), vim doesn't choke on it.

Comment: I'm not super concerned about how it displays. The file always loads correctly for me if I instead request latin-1; my question is explicitly about how to set up the editor so that it *automatically* falls back to latin-1 if utf-8 doesn't work (as it doesn't, and can't, here).

Comment: `[noeol]` makes it invalid for everything in `fileencodings`. When this fails, the value of `encoding` is used. `encoding` defaults to latin1, _unless_ a suitable value is found in the environmental variable `$LANG`, which is likely utf-8 these days. `echo $LANG` is likely to reveal the source of the ultimate utf-8 fallback. This shouldn't happen with a file that ends in a newline, however... and you won't get the `[noeol]` error. `set nofixeol` in your `.vimrc` will 'fix' this by ignoring files that don't end in newlines.

Comment: @DanielWagner While I've seen vim go a little bonkers with `[noeol]` before, it almost seems to be the combination of the leading NULL byte and the lack of a trailing eol in this case. Regardless, `$LANG` is almost certainly where the ultimate fallback is coming from.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting! I agree: with a final newline, it does fall back to latin1. I can't get your `nofixeol` trick to work though: even after setting it, a file with no final eol doesn't fall back to latin1 (and the documentation for `nofixeol` seems to imply it is used only when writing, not reading).

Comment: @DanielWagner Not working for me in a different environment either - so either that was a quirk of my earlier environment, or I accidentally changed more than one test variable. I've run into this sort of thing before, and thought that I had solved it with _something_ along those lines… but I guess that wasn't it. Sorry for the misinfo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is, because Vim uses the `utf-8` encoding. it should work when manually forcing `encoding=latin1`. However I would not recommend setting this option. An alternative is to force Vim reading that file with a latin1 encoding, like this `:e ++enc=latin1`